# Google sheets date format change

Tags: date, google-sheets, format

Google sheets default date format is 11/05/2014 I want it be like 12-Apr-2014
I already have done date format change but its not working.
Can anyone please tell me how do I change it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The formula would be

```
=TEXT(A1, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
```

This is considering that your date is in cell A1.